# PGN Viewer choices are showing up in the wrong place on the page

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

When the PGN viewer offers a choice, the choice dialog is appearing in the top left of the page, which doesn't seem correct.

No matter where I scroll or the window size, it's fixed just a few pixels below the top of the page and a consistent distance from the left. I'm guessing it's supposed to be offset from the top left of the chess board, but instead it's offset on the page globally.

Maybe a `position: relative;` is missing on the chessboard?

### Reproduction

You should be able to see the bug on this chessboard copied from [David's answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/36982) to [{Landa vs Zhu Chen, Bad Wiessee, 2006} Lichess giving a +4.7 to white. Why?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/36980). Hit Next a couple of times until the choice comes up:

```
[Event "Chess Calculation: Chapter 1"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/study/VFtoodiL/uG0A42Q9"]
[Date "2021.09.12"]
[Round ""]
[White ""]
[Black ""]
[Result "*"]
[UTCDate "2021.09.12"]
[UTCTime "13:24:02"]
[Variant "From Position"]
[Opening "?"]
[Annotator "https://lichess.org/@/sohamdas"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "r4rk1/pp2bppp/1np1p3/3q4/3Pb3/1QP3P1/P3PPBP/R1BRN1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.c4 Qf5 
    ( 1...Nxc4 2.Bxe4 Qxe4 3.Qxc4 )
2.f3 *
```

### Chrome

[image: firefox]

### Firefox

[image: chrome]